# How do I create this queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following three models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Experiment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

class Ad(models.Model):
    experiment = models.ForeignKey(Experiment, related_name='ads', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to create a queryset which returns all ads where ad.category is in ad.experiment.categories.

Some example data to talk through:
Category: ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', Cat4', 'Cat5']

Experiment: [['Exp1',['Cat2','Cat3]],['Exp2',['Cat5','Cat1']]]

Ad: [['Exp1','Cat4'],['Exp1','Cat2']]

The queryset I'm hoping to create would only return the second ad because the ad's category is in the ad's experiment's category.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to traverse the reverse relationship for experiment and then use an `F` object to access the `ad`'s `category` field in the query. The distinct is used because the experiment will have many categories so one ad may have multiple matches on the comparison.

```
from django.db.models import F
Ad.objects.filter(experiment__category=F('category')).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you so much @schillingt! I'm thinking that I don't need the .distinct() as an ad can only have one category and an experiment's categories are a unique list to begin with. Sound right?

Comment: Maybe, test it out.